# How to fix one DIV as header and one DIV as a footer with minimum code ? NO BOOTSTRAP

Tags: javascript, html

In a HTML5 webpage that is not using BOOTSTRAP or any other boilerplate I have 3 DIVS:

1. HEADER
2. CONTENT
3. FOOTER

> ```
> <HTML> <BODY> 
> <DIV name="HEADER" id="HEADER"><CENTER></CENTER></DIV>
> <DIV name="CONTENT" id="CONTENT"><CENTER></CENTER></DIV>
> <DIV name="FOOTER" id="FOOTER"><CENTER></CENTER></DIV> 
> </HTML> </BODY>
> ```

How do I fix HEADER to the top of the page and the FOOTER to the botton while letting content to scroll freely ? header and footer must not show scrollbars at all.
header and footer must have 100px of height each and both must be on-top of the CONTENT DIV.
elements of the 3 divs must be active (user must be able to click on any link)

I am looking for the most simple HTML code that works for most current browsers, desktop and mobile.

thank you
gabriel

Comment: What have you tried? Where is your code?

Comment: Try to learn html5 `<header>, <footer>` and css `position:fixed`

Comment: I am sorry, the editor deleted the code. updated. thank you for answering and trying to help

Comment: Note that the `<center>` element has been obsolete for several years.

Comment: yes, but in my case does what i need. i am wondering if search engines will penalize my site if "obsolete" tags are being used... any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
header, footer {
  position: fixed;
  min-height: 100px;
}
header {
  top: 0;
}
footer {
  bottom: 0;
}
main {
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<header></header>
<main>
  <section> Content </section>
</main>
<footer></footer>
```